# How would an iterator equivalent to itertools.count be implemented in Python without using a generator function?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

With a generator function, this is how `itertools.count` can be implemented (from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)):

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    # count(10) --> 10 11 12 13 14 ...
    # count(2.5, 0.5) -> 2.5 3.0 3.5 ...
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

I am trying to find how a similar iterator could be implemented without a generator function.

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.c = start
        self.step = step

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        n = self.c
        self.c += self.step
        return n
```

Is this the implementation?

For sure, it does not make any practical sense, the point is just to get an idea of how it is achieved with generators.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `collections.abc.Iterator` to implement count with less code

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

class count(Iterator):
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.c, self.step = start-step, step

    def __next__(self):
        self.c += self.step
        return self.c
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best practices is to write a small unit test. You can use the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) framework for that.

Here is an example with several tests which use your class in a loop and check the values of your iterator:

```
import unittest
import random


class TestCount(unittest.TestCase):
    loops = 20

    def test_default(self):
        c = Count()
        for i in range(self.loops):
            self.assertEqual(i, next(c))

    def test_start(self):
        start = random.randint(-10, 10)
        c = Count(start=start)
        for i in range(start, start + self.loops):
            self.assertEqual(i, next(c))

    def test_step_pos(self):
        step = random.randint(1, 5)
        c = Count(step=step)
        for i in range(0, self.loops, step):
            self.assertEqual(i, next(c))

    def test_step_neg(self):
        step = random.randint(-5, -1)
        c = Count(step=step)
        for i in range(0, -self.loops, step):
            self.assertEqual(i, next(c))
```